# BigInteger memory leak causes stack overflow in Java

Tags: java, stack-overflow, biginteger, fibonacci

I am trying to write an optimized fibonacci as an assignment to be able to compute fib(300) and fib(8000). Here is what I have so far (map is a HashMap).

```
public static BigInteger fibMemo(int n) {

    if (n <= 1){
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    }

    if (!map.containsKey(n)){
        map.put(n, fibMemo(n-1).add(fibMemo(n-2)));
    }
    return map.get(n);        
}
```

When I call

```
System.out.println("300: " + FibonacciMemo.fibMemo(300));
```

on its own, it works just fine.
Also,

```
System.out.println("8000: " + FibonacciMemo.fibMemo(8000));
```

works fine if I comment out the previous call to fib(300). But if I keep both calls I get a stack overflow on the recursive fibMemo. This seems very strange to me. Could someone please clarify the situation? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap; // Import Java's HashMap so we can use it
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class FibonacciMemo {
    private static HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> map = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();
    /**
     * The classic recursive implementation with no memoization. Don't care
     * about graceful error catching, we're only interested in performance.
     * 
     * @param n
     * @return The nth fibonacci number
     */
    public static int fibNoMemo(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
        }
        return fibNoMemo(n - 2) + fibNoMemo(n - 1);
    }
    /**
     * Your optimized recursive implementation with memoization. 
     * You may assume that n is non-negative.
     * 
     * @param n
     * @return The nth fibonacci number
     */
    public static BigInteger fibMemo(int n) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        if (n <= 1){
            return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
        }

        if (!map.containsKey(n)){
            map.put(n, fibMemo(n-1).add(fibMemo(n-2)));
        }
        return map.get(n);        
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Optional testing here        
        String m = "Fibonacci's real name was Leonardo Pisano Bigollo.";
        m += "\n" + "He was the son of a wealthy merchant.\n";
        System.out.println(m);
         System.out.println("300: " + FibonacciMemo.fibMemo(300));
        System.out.println("8000: " + FibonacciMemo.fibMemo(8000));
        // 46th Fibonacci = 1,836,311,903
        // 47th Fibonacci = 2,971,215,073
    }
}
```

Comment: where is map declared and how?

Comment: what is your stack trace?

Comment: In the same class as `private static HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> map = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();`

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem -- I'm getting the stack overflow even with only `fibMemo(8000)` rather than with both. Have you increased your stack size using `-Xss`?

Comment: Ditto, same results as neuronaut.  StackOverflow for 8000, regardless of whether `fib(300)` is called.  It seems you are simply up against Java's default stack size.

Comment: No I haven't. Maybe it is a memory issue?

Comment: You should not need to increase your stack size.  This should work just fine as written above.  Show us how your map is declared.

Comment: I have posted the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code. The obvious one is the stack consumption. The memoization does reduce the time complexity from exponential to linear, but still, the method has a linear stack consumption - for input value of 8000, it allocates 8000 stack frames.

As stated in the [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html), the default stack size per thread is **320kB**, which suffices for roughly 1000 - 2000 frames, which is not enough. You could increase the stack size using the `-Xss` JVM switch, but that is still not bullet proof. You should use an iterative implementation instead.

The second problem is that your static cache is never cleared, which basically causes a memory leak. You could either wrap the recursive method in another one which clears the hashmap after the recursion terminates, but that throws away a bit of the performance, because the results of one invocation cannot be reused in the following ones.

A more performant solution would be to use a proper cache implementation that doesn't require manual cleaning, but handles size limits and garbage collection on its own. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) provides such implementation.

Comment: thanks Natix. This is getting closer to my misunderstanding. Can you explain the second paragraph? The reason i didn't clear it is because i figured the computation that was done for fib(300) would then be used for fib(8000). Why does a memory leak happen here?

Comment: Well, in your program, you just compute the value for 300, then for 8000 and then terminate, so in this case, it doesn't matter. But suppose you used this class in a long running application (for example a web server): Once you called `fibMemo(8000)`, the static map would get filled with 8000 entries which would stay there and occupy the heap until the app would terminate, even if nobody ever called the method again.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, but couldn't one look at the other side of the coin? Say, you clear the cache, and then someone needs to call fib(5000). Now you have to go and recompute all of those values again.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's why I mentioned using a more sophisticated cache implementation than a plain hashmap. A cache such as the one in Guava holds on to previously computed values, but can have a size limit which assures that it doesn't grow uncontrollably or can be cleared after a specified timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your recursive algorithm is just too much for Java's default stack size.  Stack memory is optimized differently than heap in hardware, and you shouldn't use algorithms with this much recursion anyway.  Some languages can optimize tail recursion.  It seems at least in this case Java won't always optimize your code.

So the best solution imo is just to rewrite your code to use loops instead.

```
   private final static List<BigInteger> fibs = new ArrayList<>();
   static{ fibs.add( BigInteger.ZERO ); fibs.add( BigInteger.ONE ); }

   public static BigInteger lFib( int n ) {
      if( n < 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      if( n >= fibs.size() ) {
         for( int i = fibs.size(); i <= n; i++ )
            fibs.add( fibs.get(i-2).add( fibs.get(i-1) ) );
      }
      return fibs.get(n);
   }
```

Very lightly tested.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the size of thread stack which can get exhausted fir a large number of recursive calls. The solution is to provide enough stack size. You could try running the app using a vm arg `-Xss`. I tried with `-Xss2m` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
        map.put(n, fibMemo(n-1).add(fibMemo(n-2)));
```

to

```
        map.put(n, fibMemo(n-2).add(fibMemo(n-1)));
```

It works fine.

The former's calling sequences are

```
fibMemo(10) nested level = 0
fibMemo(9) nested level = 1
fibMemo(8) nested level = 2
fibMemo(7) nested level = 3
fibMemo(6) nested level = 4
fibMemo(5) nested level = 5
fibMemo(4) nested level = 6
fibMemo(3) nested level = 7
fibMemo(2) nested level = 8
fibMemo(1) nested level = 9
fibMemo(0) nested level = 9
fibMemo(1) nested level = 8
fibMemo(2) nested level = 7
fibMemo(3) nested level = 6
fibMemo(4) nested level = 5
fibMemo(5) nested level = 4
fibMemo(6) nested level = 3
fibMemo(7) nested level = 2
fibMemo(8) nested level = 1
```

The latter's calling sequences are

```
fibMemo(10) nested level = 0
fibMemo(8) nested level = 1
fibMemo(6) nested level = 2
fibMemo(4) nested level = 3
fibMemo(2) nested level = 4
fibMemo(0) nested level = 5
fibMemo(1) nested level = 5
fibMemo(3) nested level = 4
fibMemo(1) nested level = 5
fibMemo(2) nested level = 5
fibMemo(5) nested level = 3
fibMemo(3) nested level = 4
fibMemo(4) nested level = 4
fibMemo(7) nested level = 2
fibMemo(5) nested level = 3
fibMemo(6) nested level = 3
fibMemo(9) nested level = 1
fibMemo(7) nested level = 2
fibMemo(8) nested level = 2
```

The latter is less consumption of the stack.